# how to remove date identifier and special charactar from string

Tags: perl

I want to remove date identifier and * from string .

```
$string = "*102015 Supplied air hood";
$output = "Supplied air hood";
```

i have used

```
$string =~ s/[#\%&\""*+]//g;
$string =~ s/^\s+//;
```

what should i used to get string value = "Supplied air hood";

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a bunch of characters in your character class, except for the ones you're actually trying to match!

Answer (score 3):

To remove everything from the string up to the first space, you can write

```
$str =~ s/^\S*\s+//;
```

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar: I am concerned that you say there isn't always a date at the start of the line. If you always want to delete the first field up to the first set of spaces then this will work for you, but if you need to check whether the line starts with a star and a date before you remove anything then you need something more elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern doesn't contain numbers. It would remove the `*`, but nothing else. If you want to remove a `*` followed by six digits and a blank at the beginning of the string, do it like this:

```
$string =~ s/^\*\d{6} //;
```

However, if that string always contains a pattern like this, you don't need a regular expression substitution. You can simply take a substring.

```
my $output = substr $string, 8;
```

That will assign the content of `$string` starting from the 9th character

Comment: You have to quote the `*` quantifier. So the regex would look like `$string =~s/^\*\d{6} //;`

Comment: yeah right but some time date identifier may come or may not come so using  my $output = substr $string,8 will also not work

Comment: $string =~ s/^\*\d{6} //; i tried this but was not working

Comment: could you please elaborate i did not understand @simbbaque

Answer (score 0):

The script below does what you want, assuming that the date always appears at the beginning the line, and that it is follow by exactly one space.

```
use strict;
use warnings;


while (<DATA>)
{
    # skip one or more characters not a space
    # then skip exactly one space
    # then capture all remaining characters
    # and assign them to $s
    my ($s) = $_ =~ /[^ ]+ (.*)/;
    print $s, "\n";
}

__DATA__
*110115 first date
*110115 second date
*110315 third date
```

Output is:

```
first date
second date
third date
```